# Access SQL Subquery in Transform

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, join, crosstab

OK, I have spent the last few hours searching and tweaking my queries, and have taken this about as far as I can.  I am using MS Jet to execute queries on an Access database.  In its simplest form, I have three tables of Items (work order details), Tasks and a table relating them to see if a task on a particular item has been completed.  The first two tables are linked by a Task Group ID (TGID). So the schema looks like this in its simplest form:

- WODetail: ID, TGID
- Task: ID, TGID
- WOTask: ID, WODID, TaskID, Done

I can pull up the data I need with the following query, just not in the format I want:

`Select WOD.ID, T.ID, (Select Done From WOTask Where WOTask.WODID = WOD.ID And WOTask.TaskID = T.ID) As Done From WODetail WOD Inner Join Task T On WOD.TGID = T.TGID Where T.TGID = 1 Group By WOD.ID, T.ID`

This gives results like:

```
WOD.ID T.ID Done 
600 3 True 
600 6 False 
600 7 False 
600 8 False 
602 3 True 
602 6 False 
602 7 False 
602 8 False 
607 3 True 
607 6 False
etc
```

The data is correct, what I would like to do is Transform (Pivot, Crosstab, whatever) the TaskID horizontally, and have the Done field indicate the status of each task for each item, like this:

```
WOD.ID 3 6 7 8  <--- TaskID going horizontally
600 True False False False
602 True False False False
607 True False False False
608 False False False False
```

I had to use a subquery to get the Done field to work properly, as there are no entries in WOTask if the task has not been performed yet.  Yes, I have tried Left Joining WOTask but have not got the Done field to report properly.  This is the closest I have gotten with the crosstab query:

`Transform Max(Select Done From WOTask Where WOTask.WODID = WOD.ID And WOTask.TaskID = T.ID) Select WOD.ID From WODetail WOD Inner Join Task T On WOD.TGID = T.TGID Where T.TGID = 1 Group By WOD.ID Pivot T.ID`

but I receive the error: "The Microsoft Jet database engine does not recognize 'WOD.ID' as a valid field name or expression".  I assume this is because the subquery after the Transform is being executed before the Join?  It doesn't seem logical to put a Join on the subquery; I want it to match up the values with those from the Select statement, like it did in the original query.

Any suggestions here?  Aside from programmatically going through the data, I am at a loss.  I would rather not have to create entries in WOTask for work not yet started, but can if I must.  Is there something inherently wrong in how I am approaching this?  Thanks for any help/direction!

Comment: Can you also include an example of what the desired result set must look like?

Comment: Edited as per request.  Thanks for looking!

Comment: Cool. You should look at the syntax for PIVOT again - notice how you must specify the values which you want to become columns, explicitly. I haven't come across ways of dynamically returning a variable number of columns that is somehow inferred from the table data (without making cartwheels with dynamic SQL stuff, of course)

Comment: I have used PIVOT before with just a field; for example pulling up time card totals by employee (rows) and date (columns).  Just for kicks I tried modifying the last part to read `PIVOT T.ID IN (3, 6, 7, 8)` but got the error "The field is too small to accept the amount of data you attempted to add. Try inserting or pasting less data."

Comment: I have also tried using `Transform First(Done) Select WOD.ID As WODID From (WODetail WOD Inner Join Task T On WOD.TGID = T.TGID) Left Join WOTask WT On WT.WODID = WOD.ID Where T.TGID = 1 Group By WOD.ID Pivot T.ID` which gives me the rows and columns that I need, but it shows the same Done values across all columns.  Similar results for Min & Max

Comment: @Biscuits :  I was able to get very close with `TRANSFORM First(WOTask.Done) SELECT WODetail.ID FROM (WODetail INNER JOIN Task ON WODetail.TGID = Task.TGID) INNER JOIN WOTask ON (WOTask.TaskID = Task.ID) AND (WODetail.ID = WOTask.WODID) GROUP BY WODetail.ID PIVOT Task.ID IN (3, 6, 7, 8)` which gives me blanks for the nonexistent fields and proper values where I expect them.  Since I am doing the codebehind in VB.Net, I can do another query to give me the column headings and turn that into comma separated values for the PIVOT list.  Not pretty but works until a better solution presents itself.

Comment: If this proves difficult, I would try to take advantage of application code to further manipulate the data.